# php - sendmail not working on ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: php, ubuntu, sendmail

Can anyone please help me to sort out mail() function issue, it is not sending an email. I am not sure but it due to virtual host setup. Contents of my `'/etc/hosts'` file are -

```
127.0.1.1 App App
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I searched a lot and found that I need to update "/etc/hosts" file: 
**nano /etc/hosts**

to look like this: **127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost 
yourhostname**

but when I type **hostname** in terminal , it shows **App** , I think it is because of virtual host.

I run following command to check connection -

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
```

and the output is -

```
Trying 209.85.201.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a solution yet, but if you want to remove "App" as hostname (your text sounds a bit like that) , you need to remove the first line of your '/etc/hosts'.

Try again and try to send us the error output (on the website and in the webserverlog ('/var/log/apache2/error.log' or at path configured in '/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini')).

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I can't remove that line, it could affect other functionalities.

Comment: Ok @SachinVairagi but pls try to send the error messages mentioned above.